# Changing border left color based on value

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a table where I want each row's border-left to differ based on priority level.

My HTML:

```
<tr id= "rows"> 
      <td data-title="Link"><img src="form_blank.png" title="Agreement" width="40"/> <a href="${gr1.u_url.getDisplayValue()}" target = "_blank">${gr1.short_description.getDisplayValue()}</a></td>
      <td data-title="State"> ${gr1.state.getDisplayValue()} </td>
      <td data-title="Due" input="date" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY">${gr1.due_date.getDisplayValue().substring(0,10)} </td>
</tr>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script>
function bordercolor() {
    var leftborder = document.getElementById("rows");
    if (${gr1.priority.getDisplayValue()} = 1){
        leftborder.style.borderLeft = "solid 10px #b30000";}
    else if (${gr1.priority.getDisplayValue()} = 2){
        leftborder.style.borderLeft = "solid 10px #ffa500";}
    else if (${gr1.priority.getDisplayValue()} = 3){
        leftborder.style.borderLeft = "solid 10px #ffff00";}
    else if (${gr1.priority.getDisplayValue()} = 4){
        leftborder.style.borderLeft = "solid 10px #7fbf7f";}
    else {leftborder.style.borderLeft = "solid 10px #006600";}
}

</script>
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `${...}` means inside your code, hopefully I'm not missing something obvious but it's nothing I could recognize as valid. It smells to some preprocessing replacement logic but without confirmation is hard to say for sure.

Something else that is wrong at first sight is the fact that you're using assign operator (`=`) on the `if` statement instead of the equal operator (`==`)

Another problem is that `tr` can't take a border. Below you'll find how I would implement this. Notice the use of css classes instead of manipulating directly the element border. I'm also asigning an id to the table and using this control to apply styles instead of rows

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">
  <tr> 
      <td data-title="Link"><img src="form_blank.png" title="Agreement" width="40"/> <a href="${gr1.u_url.getDisplayValue()}" target = "_blank">${gr1.short_description.getDisplayValue()}</a></td>
      <td data-title="State"> ${gr1.state.getDisplayValue()} </td>
      <td data-title="Due" input="date" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY">${gr1.due_date.getDisplayValue().substring(0,10)} </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.priority-1 td:first-child {
  border-left: solid 10px #b30000;
}

.priority-2 td:first-child {
  border-left: solid 10px #ffa500; 
}

.priority-3 td:first-child {
  border-left: solid 10px #ffff00;  
}

.priority-4 td:first-child {
  border-left: solid 10px #7fbf7f;  
}

.priority-other td:first-child {
  border-left: solid 10px #006600; 
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function bordercolor() {
    var priority = ${gr1.priority.getDisplayValue()};
    var table = document.getElementById("table");

    if (priority <= 4)
        table.className = "priority-" + priority;
    else
        table.className = "priority-other";
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t4jnhas8/)

Comment: the ${} syntax is jelly script used in ServiceNow.  I changed the operator to == but still no luck.  thanks!

Comment: @Dave: do each row on that table has the same id and you want to modify all? If that's the case, it's not going to work

Comment: ah ok that makes sense.  I have a <j:while test="${gr1.next()}"> loop that looks through a table and generates each row.  How can I modify my JS code above to work in this instance?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- You should be styling the leftmost td, you can't have a different left border on a row
- The id attribute should be unique, rows would be better as a class

Leverage the variables you have when possible. Would this work?

```
<tr class= "rows" data-priority="${gr1.priority.getDisplayValue()}"> 
  <td data-title="Link"><img src="form_blank.png" title="Agreement" width="40"/> <a href="${gr1.u_url.getDisplayValue()}" target = "_blank">${gr1.short_description.getDisplayValue()}</a></td>
  <td data-title="State"> ${gr1.state.getDisplayValue()} </td>
  <td data-title="Due" input="date" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY">${gr1.due_date.getDisplayValue().substring(0,10)} </td>
</tr>
```

And css like this, targeting the data-priority attribute

```
.rows[data-priority="1"] td:first-child{ border-left: 2px solid #234324;}
.rows[data-priority="2"] td:first-child{ /* your css for this one */}
.rows[data-priority="3"] td:first-child{ /* your css for this one */}
/* and so on */
```